# How to obtain the actual string like it is displayed in the UITextField while the user is typing?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

There is the UITextFieldDelegate protocol, which offers only one reasonable method to get notified about changes in the UITextField:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

This method doesn't provide the actual string like it is visible in the textField. It gets called *before* the text property in the UITextField updates to the new text. The `string` is only what has changed.

I guess the only way to find out, is to assemble the text manually from this information. How would I go about this? Must I invent the solution or is there already one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just might not need a delegate method.

If you're using IB, you can create an IBAction like this

`-(IBAction)myTextFieldDidChange:(id)sender{ 

 NSString*aString = myTextField.text;

}`

just connect this function to your corresponding UITextField(which in this case, myTextField)
for events ValueChanged (UIControlEventValueChanged)

Comment: Thanks man! That was the solution. But you need UIControlEventEditingChanged instead :)